# Jquery intercept the cancel click, when I select a file

Tags: jquery, events, upload, submit

in my case, when I click on choose file input I i set a variable to 1.

Once you choose the file this variable remains at 1.

if it cancels, closes the window without selecting a file to upload I would like to return this variable to 0 it possible?

tnx

Comment: More detail required here. I assume you are cancelling a dialog? If so, which plugin are you using? Some code would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct I would go the other way. If you click the file chooser set the variable to 0, and only set the variable to 1 if the value of the file input changes.

Html

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
```

Js

```
var x = 0;
$('#file').click(function() {
    x = 0;
});
$('#file').change(function() {
    x = 1;
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/JWRgY/ for a demo.

Comment: yes, thank you friend!!!
This is the finally code work perfectly for me http://jsfiddle.net/JWRgY/1/